# Setup Stuck on 99% - Clearing Cache

Tags: magento-2.1, setup, web-setup-wizard

On setting up a new Magento instance (2.1), the process is getting stuck it seams at 99%, on

> Caches Clearing:

Is this normal? How long should this process take and is there any task after this that should execute that won't? Lastly, should I manually attempt to clear the cache now to make sure it is done?

FYI the PHP max_execution time is set to 1800, so I don't think it is timing out.
[image: max execution time set to 1800]

[image: Magento Setup Stuck on Caches Clearing 98% or 99%]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trialing and continuing on-wards I worked out that there were no steps that have been missed as a result of it stopping here. I think this is caused by a specific configuration on IIS (in this case as a Windows Azure Web App).

Comment: were you able to get this working on azure? how?

Comment: I didn't try after this as it had worked and has continued to work sufficiently.